# Parsing nested XML in Databricks

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I am trying to p

I am trying to read the XML into a data frame and trying to flatten the data using explode as below.

val df = spark.read.format("xml").option("rowTag","on").option("inferschema","true").load("filepath")
val parsxml= df
.withColumn("exploded_element", explode(("prgSvc.element"))).

I am getting the below error.

```
command-5246708674960:4: error: type mismatch;
found   : String("prgSvc.element")
required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
.withColumn("exploded_element", explode(("prgSvc.element")))**

Before reading the XML into the data frame, I also tried to manually assign a custom schema and read the XML file. But the output is all NULL. Could you please let me know if my approach is valid and how to resolve this issue and achieve the output.
Thank you.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
import spark.implicits._

val parsxml= df .withColumn("exploded_element", explode($"prgSvc.element"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The above code gives me the below error,

Comment: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`prgSvc.element`' given input columns: [prgSvcs];;          When I change the explode column name as prgSvcs, the error is org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: No such struct field element in prgSvc;    In this case what should be my rowTag while reading the XML file?

Comment: Row tag should be root. Then print the schema before using the column names above